# How to share a global dict between Cloud Run instances in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-run

I'm building a flask server in python with Cloud Run, for a chatbot to call.

Sometimes if user wants to do something with the chatbot, the bot need ask the user to login to a 3rd party server before doing the things.

I have two routes:

- Route 1 is "/login", it returns a simple iframe which will open a login page in a 3rd party server, generate a "session_id", and save some info I already get to a global variable dict called "runtimes" with the "session_id" as key, so that I can use it later when visitor successfully logged in.
- Route 2 is "/callback/<session_id>". After user successfully login to its account, the 3rd party server will call this route with a token in url parameters. Then I will use the "session_id" to read the saved info from "runtimes", and do later things.

It works well in my local machine. But in Google Cloud Run, because it support multiple instances,  sometimes it will trigger a new instance when server calls "callback", so it cannot get the "runtime" because they are in different instances.

I know that I can save the runtimes dict to a database to solve this problem, but it looks too overkill...Just not seem right.

Is there any easy way that I can make the "runtimes" be shared between instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to use a central point of storage: database, memorystore, firestore,... something out of Cloud Run itself.

You can also try the Cloud Run execution runtime v2 that allow you to mount a network disk, such as Cloud Storage or Filestore. You can imagine to store the session data in a file which has the name of the session ID.

***Note**: On Cloud Run side, something is cooking, but it's not 100% safe, it will be a best effort. A database backup will be required even with that new feature*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Firestore database now. But since I don't need to persist the data, it just feels a little weird to use database do a memory thing.

I just saw in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems) says that Cloud Run has a "built-in memory file system". But there is no guide of how to use that. I wonder if anyone knows how to use this and if this is cross-instances.

Comment: Cloud Run has a in memory file system (TMPFS). You can write in the `/tmp` directory. But it's dedicated to the instance and not shared between several. Therefore, it won't solve your issue.